# How Transaction management work with one-phase and two-phase commit?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, websphere

I am trying to understand transaction management but am not able to find resources to explain the below questions so I would appreciate it if someone enlighten me.

- is one phase commit can be a global transaction?
- is one phase commit is a local transaction?
- can I create a local transaction at the application server (EX:- Websphere )?
- is any transaction created and managed by the application server is a global transaction?

Comment: Does this WebSphere documentation help? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=resources-transaction-support-in-websphere-application-server

Comment: A local transaction means one-phase commit. A global transaction will typically use two-phase commit if needed (i.e. if there is more than one resource) but can often optimize and use only one-phase commit if only a single resource has been updated. A transaction created by an application server's transaction manager is typically global (but doesn't have to use two phase!) but any transaction created directly for a resource will be local even if the code runs in an application server. If you use JDBC transactions rather than managed transactions they will be local. Read the docs for more.